# Swift has error : "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation"

Tags: swift, func

So i have code in xcode playground and got the error [error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNodd.png)

and this is the excercise i do
**Return the Factorial**
Create a function that takes an integer and returns the factorial of that integer. That is, the integer multiplied by all positive lower integers.

and this is my code

```
func factorial(_ num: Int) -> Int {
    var result :Int = 0
    for _ in num...1 {
        result = num * (num - 1)
    }
    return result
}
```

print(factorial(12)) //error in this line

but in terminal got this output:

[image: error in terminal]

Comment: Your code wouldn't calculate a factorial correctly even without the error. But the error itself is clear.  In `num...1`, the value of `num` is bigger than 1. In Swift, that's illegal; ranges go up, not down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error message - the upper bound of the range has to be greater than or equal to the lower.

Therefore you'll need to rewrite the method differently.  You also have a fundamental flaw in your code - your maths logic is wrong - result will be overwritten every time, rather than accumulating a total.  Adopting a similar approach to the question you can do this:

```
func factorial(_ num: Int) -> Int {
  var result :Int = 1

  guard num > 0 else {return result}. //0! is 1 not 0
  var num = num
  while num > 0 {
    result *= num
    num -= 1
  }
  return result
}
```

There is a more elegant way of performing this using recursion, which avoids the ugly `var num=num`

```
func fac2(_ num: Int, total: Int = 1) -> Int {
  return num > 0 ? fac2(num-1, total: total * num) : total
}
```